# Why is $\operatorname{Aut}(\mathbb{Z}_p)\cong \mathbb{Z}_p^*$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, number-theory, algebraic-number-theory, p-adic-number-theory, automorphism-group

Let $\mathbb{Z}_p$ denote the $p$-adic integers. Why is $\operatorname{Aut}(\mathbb{Z}_p)\cong \mathbb{Z}_p^*$?

I know that $\operatorname{Aut}(\mathbb{Z}/p^n\mathbb{Z})\cong(\mathbb{Z}/p^n\mathbb{Z})^*$, but I'm not sure which result from group theory to apply.

Comment: Show each group homomorphism $f \colon \mathbf Z_p \to \mathbf Z_p$ is multiplication by a unique $p$-adic integer $c$: $f(x) = cx$ for all $x \in \mathbf Z_p$. Do that by showing $f$ induces a group homomorphism $\mathbf Z/p^n\mathbf Z$ to $\mathbf Z/p^n\mathbf Z$, this must be multiplication by a $c_n \in \mathbf Z/p^n\mathbf Z$, and $c_{n+1} \equiv c_n \bmod p^n\mathbf Z$. Automorphisms of an abelian group are invertible endomorphisms, so if you show the endomorphisms of $\mathbf Z_p$ are multiplication by $p$-adic integers then its automorphisms are multiplication by $\mathbf Z_p^\times$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is an injective map
$$
\mathbb{Z}_p^\times \to \text{Aut}_{\text{ab. gp.}}(\mathbb{Z}_p)
$$
given by taking $\alpha$ to left-multiplication by $\alpha$ (this is true for any ring).

You wish to know this is surjective. Say $\phi$ is an automorphism of $\mathbb{Z}_p$. Then $\phi$ has to preserve the subgroup $p^n\mathbb{Z}_p$, and therefore $\phi$ has to induce an automorphism of $\mathbb{Z}/p^n\mathbb{Z}$.

This automorphism must be multiplication by a unit $\beta_n$ in $\mathbb{Z}/p^n\mathbb{Z}$, since all automorphisms of this abelian group arise in this way (you seem to already believe this, but proof: take the fact above that was "true for any ring" and observe that injective functions from finite sets to themselves are bijective).

So we have a whole bunch of $\beta_n$. Since for $n > m$ the diagram

$\require{AMScd}$
\begin{CD}
\mathbb{Z}_p / p^n \mathbb{Z}_p  @>\phi>> \mathbb{Z}_p / p^n \mathbb{Z}_p \\
@V  V V @VV  V\\
\mathbb{Z}_p / p^m \mathbb{Z}_p  @>\phi>> \mathbb{Z}_p / p^m \mathbb{Z}_p 
\end{CD}
commutes, where the vertical arrows are the natural reduction and the horizontal are the maps induced by $\phi$, we must have that $\beta_n$ reduces to $\beta_m$ mod $p^n$.

So the $\beta_n$ form an element $\beta$ of
$$
\varprojlim{(\mathbb{Z}_p/p^n\mathbb{Z}_p})^\times = \mathbb{Z}_p^\times,
$$
and our automorphism $\phi$ must be multiplication by this $\beta$.

Comment: Alternatively $\phi(p^n\Bbb{Z}_p)= p^n\Bbb{Z}_p$ means that $\phi$ is continuous so $\phi(n)=\phi(1)n$ for all integer gives $\phi(a)=\phi(1) a$ for all $p$-adic integer.

Comment: @reuns your argument is prettier and you should post it as an answer!

Comment: IMO it is the same as yours, just different wording.

Comment: @hunter Could you explain why $\phi$ has to induce an automorphism of $\mathbb{Z}/p^n\mathbb{Z}$?

Comment: @ponchan we need to check that if $x$ is congruent to $y$ mod $p^n$, then $\phi(x) = \phi(y) \mod p^n$. But if $x = y + p^na$ then $\phi(x) = \phi(y) + p^n\phi(a)$ since in particular $\phi$ is additive.